# TSQL matching as many comma-separated tags as possible

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A table contains a `Title` field and a `Tags` field. The tags are generated via latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA) from documents and can be e.g. '*fish, oven, time*', '*BBQ, beer*' or ' *meat, BBQ*'. The length of the tags is not fixed.

Given a set of tags, how to find the record with the maximum amount of tags matching no matter the order of the tags?

So, if '*BBQ, meat*' is given the best result should be '*meat, BBQ*'. If '*BBQ, fish, cream*' is given all three records can be returned (they all have one matching tag).

Comment: Split the words out into a separate table one per row with a a FK back to the document

Comment: How many times does "fish" match in "One fish, two fish, red fish, blue fish?" Does that count as one or five? _(Four, Sir!)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/6468577) and Create this one

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getCountOfMatch ( @mainString VARCHAR(MAX),  @searchString nvarchar(max))
    RETURNS
      INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @returnCount INT

        SELECT 
            @returnCount = COUNT(1)
        FROM 
            splitstring(@mainString) A INNER JOIN 
            splitstring(@searchString) B ON A.Name = B.Name

        RETURN @returnCount
    END
```

and

```
    SELECT TOP 1 // What you want
      Title,
      Tags
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.Title,
            A.Tags,
            dbo.getCountOfMatch(A.Tags, @search) CountTags -- The number of matches.
        FROM
            TABLE A
    ) B
    ORDER BY B.CountTags DESC
```

**UPDATED**

```
DECLARE @searchText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'BBQ, meat'
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            Table
        WHERE '

SELECT
    @query += 
    (
        SELECT
            'Tags like ''%' + A.Name + '%'' AND ' -- Dont forget trim!
        FROM 
            splitstring(@searchText) A
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    )

SELECT @query = LEFT(@query, LEN(@query) - 4) + 'ORDER BY LEN(Tags)' -- For exactly matching: LEN(Tags) = LEN(@searchText)

EXEC sp_executesql  @query
```

Query look like;

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        Table
    WHERE 
        Tags like '%BBQ%' AND 
        Tags like '%meat%'
    ORDER BY LEN(Tags)
```

Comment: Works well but is intensely slow, even on a small sample (on 14K rows takes 17 secs here).

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with two UDFs, you can return a hit rate (percent) for a search.

For example

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Match-Rate]('Dog,House,Custom',',','The dog house is red',' ')
```

Returns 0.6666  -- 2 of the 3 words/phrases were found.

Each can have their own delimiter

Only Distinct words are tested to avoid inflating the results

I also included a soundex (this is optional)

1st UDF is stand alone and can be used independently.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL , Key_Value varchar(max))

As

Begin
   Declare @intPos int,@SubStr varchar(max)
   Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
   Set @String = Replace(@String,@delimeter+@delimeter,@delimeter)
   While @IntPos > 0
      Begin
         Set @SubStr = Substring(@String, 0, @IntPos)
         Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@SubStr)
         Set @String = Replace(@String, @SubStr + @delimeter, '')
         Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
      End
   Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@String)
   Return 
End
```

The second UDF requires the first

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Match-Rate] (@SearchFor varchar(max),@SearchForDelim varchar(5),@SearchIn varchar(max),@SearchInDelim varchar(5))

-- Syntax : Select [dbo].[udf-Str-Match-Rate]('Dog,House,Custom',',','The dog house is red',' ')

Returns money
AS
  BEGIN

    Declare @RetVal money

    ;with cteSearchFor  as (Select Distinct Key_Value from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@SearchFor ,@SearchForDelim))
         ,cteSearchIn as (Select Distinct Key_Value from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@SearchIn,@SearchInDelim))
         ,cteWordCnt as (Select Words=cast(count(*) as money) From cteSearchFor)
    Select @RetVal = isnull(Count(*)/max(Words),0)
      From cteSearchFor S 
      Join cteWordCnt W on 1=1
      Join cteSearchIn C
        on S.Key_Value = C.Key_Value
        or Soundex(S.Key_Value) = Soundex(C.Key_Value)

    Return @RetVal

  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table tags and populate using  [stringsplit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string/10914602#10914602)

```
tags
title PK
tag   PK  

select title, count(*) 
from tags 
where tag in ('BBQ', 'fish', 'cream') 
group by title 
having count(*) > 1

SELECT * 
from table 
join dbo.splitstring(table.tags)
```